# mobiscroll date picker show 29 days in march 2013.

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

I used mobiscroll date picker in my view.It works fine but when i  select 30th march 2013 it shows only 29 days selectable.i don't get it, is there any setting for that.Please help me.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please paste some code on how are you initializing the scroller

Answer (score 2):

I solved myself the working code is following

```
$(function(){
    $('#startdate').mobiscroll().date({
        invalid: {  },
        theme: 'default',
        display: 'modal',
        mode: 'scroller',
        dateOrder: 'mmD ddyy'
    }); 

 });
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to see if you were using the 'invalid' option. Btw, you can ignore it completely, there's no need to pass an empty object.